# NiceMatrix, rotated cells and row height

Tags: rotating, nicematrix, tabularray

I am trying to create a table in the `NiceTabularX` environment, with cells in the first row rotated using the `\rotate` command. However, it seems that the height of the rotated row does not depend on the length of its content, but is actually close to the width of the widest columns it is made of. Hence, the rotated content of the first row either gets out of the table, or is cramped over several lines to fit in there (which is not what I want). How would it be possible to make sure that `NiceTabularX` adjusts the height of the first row to make its content fit in it?

Thank you so much for your help!

Here is a reduced example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
If my table is wide enough, I have no problem to make the content of the first row, once it's rotated, fit in the cell:\par
\begin{NiceTabularX}{15cm}{*{4}{X[c]}}[hvlines]
    \RowStyle{\rotate}
    Short & Verylong & Tiny & Medium \\
    E & F & G & H \\
    I & J & K & L \\
    M & N & O & P\\
\end{NiceTabularX}

However, as soon as I want to reduce the size of the table, the content of the row stops fitting. It seems that, instead of adjusting the height of first row, it takes the width of its widest element:\par
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{NiceTabularX}{5cm}{*{4}{X[c]}}[hvlines]
    \RowStyle{\rotate}
    Short & Verylong & Tiny & Medium \\
    E & F & G & H \\
    I & J & K & L \\
    M & N & O & P\\
\end{NiceTabularX}

I would like to have a table that has the same size as the second one, but where the top row would be high enough for all the text of the cells to fit in it, and without having to add the \verb!\vspace! to avoid overlapping the preceding text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1** This approach is using the package `tabularray`.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx} % for rotatebox
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    
    
\begin{tblr}{width= 15cm,
        vlines,
        hlines,
        colspec=*{4}{X[c]}, 
        row{1} = {abovesep=4pt}
    }
    \rotatebox{90}{Short} & \rotatebox{90}{Verylong}  &  \rotatebox{90}{Tiny} &  \rotatebox{90}{Medium} \\
    E & F & G & H \\
    I & J & K & L \\
    M & N & O & P\\ 
    \end{tblr}  

\bigskip
    
\begin{tblr}{width= 5cm,
        vlines,
        hlines,
        colspec=*{4}{X[c]},
        row{1} = {abovesep=4pt}
    }
    \rotatebox{90}{Short} & \rotatebox{90}{Verylong}  &  \rotatebox{90}{Tiny} &  \rotatebox{90}{Medium} \\
    E & F & G & H \\
    I & J & K & L \\
    M & N & O & P\\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

**Option 2** With `nicematrix`, but using `\rotatebox` from the package `graphicx` like in option 1. (Instead of `\RowStyle{\rotate}`)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{graphicx} % for rotatebox   
\newcommand{\rotnd}[1]{\rotatebox{90}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabularX}{15cm}{*{4}{X[c]}}[hvlines,cell-space-limits=3pt]
    \rotnd{Short} & \rotnd{Verylong} & \rotnd{Tiny} & \rotnd{Medium} \\
    E & F & G & H \\
    I & J & K & L \\
    M & N & O & P\\
\end{NiceTabularX}

\bigskip

\begin{NiceTabularX}{5cm}{*{4}{X[c]}}[hvlines, cell-space-limits=3pt]
    \rotnd{Short} & \rotnd{Verylong} & \rotnd{Tiny} & \rotnd{Medium} \\
    E & F & G & H \\
    I & J & K & L \\
    M & N & O & P\\
\end{NiceTabularX}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, option 2 works perfectly well!